# What is the procedure to deal with bug-related questions?

Tags: discussion

What's the general way of dealing with questions, that do not and cannot have a valid answer, because of for example the issue in focus is an unresolved bug (possible example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/how-to-write-into-multiple-files#comment2605_1044)). Should one still accept an answer ("It is a bug.") or just wait for an indefinite time until Wolfram Research fixes it? I understand that there might be a concern here (on SE) as unanswered questions hinder the site's statistics. So it might not be a good idea at all to post assumed bugs. Opinions?

Comment: The bug tag is for SE system bugs.

Comment: Relevant [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/tags-do-we-need-tags-about-bugs).

Comment: Another relevant [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/tags-should-we-have-a-tag-about-bugs-take-two). (Missed it the first time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer "it is a bug" (when coming from a trustworthy source, e.g. WRI employee) should be accepted in cases when a given function and / or its specific use is the main focus of the question, and work-arounds aren't what the asker wants.

The reason I think so is that this will be more useful for new users. Once they are directed to the question, they have a concrete answer, so that they can move on, decide what work-arounds are acceptable to them, possibly ask further questions etc. Seeing a long-standing question without an answer is quite frustrating.

Comment: I agree with the usefulness of such posts. My only problem here is that usually no one cares to write such a simple answer (I guess they find it too unrewarding), and even if that happens,  it is not obvious (at least for me) who is a trustworthy WRI source.

Comment: @Istvan I think any WRI person who definitely states that "this is a bug" is a trustworthy source.

Comment: I meant to say I do not know who are WRI people around.

Comment: @Istvan They usually write this in their profile. Some (incpomplete) list: Arnoud, Andy, Andrew Moylan, Brett, Daniel Lichtblau, Oliver (ruebenko), Sasha ( I used surnames when the first name alone might have been ambiguous).

Comment: Thanks Leonid. I shall look profiles more often in the future.

Comment: Just to be sure, does that mean, that in an attempt to answer answered-in-a-comment questions, one should post an answer with summary of the comments and expect gratitude from doing that? Still relevant in 2018.

Comment: @Johu Yes, I think that whoever takes the time to post a normal full-fledged answer, for a question that so far has only been answered in comments, can expect gratitude from the community (votes etc.), even if the answer is based on comments written by others.